# VSCode - open remote from cli

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use the new VS Code remote feature all the time and it is superb. I'm wondering if it is possible to open a specific ssh host / folder from the cli. That way I can script a spin up of my dev environment (vm, vs-code, etc)!

I had a look at `code-insiders --help` but couldn't see anything that would allow me to do this. That perhaps makes this a feature request, but thought I'd post here before doing so on the github repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run this on your cmd or PowerShell

```
code --remote ssh-remote+<remoteHost> <remotePath>
```

source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/656#issuecomment-584209378

Comment: Also now documented here, with some additional options: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal

Comment: note that unlike most other ssh tools the remote path must be the full absolute path